# Timer triggered Durable function schedule

Tags: azure-functions, scheduled-tasks, azure-durable-functions, azure-http-trigger, timer-trigger

I am currently building an azure durable function for my organization. The requirement is to run this orchestration every weekday during midnight. With eternal functions we can only provide a delay. How can I achieve this goal through a cron expression as such?

Can I create a Timer triggered Durable function? Is there any limitation?
Or should I create a HTTP Triggered durable function in which the orchestrator waits for an external event; and then have a normal timer trigger azure function raise that event according to the Cron expression?

Comment: Yes, you can create a timer triggered durable function with require corn expression to run midnight every weekday.

Comment: But the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55704894/does-azure-durable-function-support-cron-jobs) here says we cant have a cron expression. I assume it signifies that we cant have timer triggered durable function. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, you can create the timer durable function. I've posted the sample as answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can define timer-triggered function with `DurableOrchestrationClient` input binding. Please see below sample declaration:

```
[FunctionName("TimerDurableFunctionStarter")]
public static async Task Run(
    [TimerTrigger("0 */1 * * * *")] TimerInfo info,
    [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient timerDurableOrchestratorStarter)
{
   string instanceId = await timerDurableOrchestratorStarter.StartNewAsync("<<OrchestratorFunctionName>>");
}
```

Comment: DurableClient attribute seems not supported in .Net Worker (Isolated Process)

Answer (score 0):

If using dotnet isolated durable function you have to change the type of the client to **DurableTaskClient**.

Example timer that triggers an orchestration(when moving to production, consider changing 'RunOnStartup' to false to avoid unwanted effects on function scaling).

```
     [Function("TimerStart")]
        public async Task TimerStart(
         [TimerTrigger("0 */15 * * * *", RunOnStartup = true)] TimerInfo myTimer,
           [DurableClient] DurableTaskClient client,
           FunctionContext executionContext)
        {
            ILogger logger = executionContext.GetLogger("TimerStart");

            string instanceId = await client.ScheduleNewOrchestrationInstanceAsync(
                nameof(MyOrchestration));

            logger.LogInformation("Timer started orchestration with ID = '{instanceId}'.", instanceId);

            if (myTimer.ScheduleStatus is not null)
            {
                logger.LogInformation($"Next timer schedule at: {myTimer.ScheduleStatus.Next}");
            }

        }
```